# Find the first prime fibonacci number larger than a given minimum

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, coding-style, segmentation-fault

I am trying to solve a problem but getting segmentation fault , not able to find what is wrong
the problem is you have to find the first fibonacci number greater then 227000 which is also a prime , call it X and return the sum of all prime divisors of X+1

```
#include<iostream>
    int main(){
        int n = 227000;
        int prime[1000000];
        std::cout<<"lll";
        int i;
        for(i = 2; i<1000;i++){
            if(!prime[i]) continue;
            int j;
            for(j=i*i;j<1000000;j+=i){
                prime[j] = 0;
            }
        }
        int num = 1;
        int nextnum = 1;
        int newnum;
        while(1){
            newnum = num+nextnum;
            if(newnum>n && prime[newnum]) break;
            num = nextnum;
            nextnum = newnum;
        }
        int sum = 1;
        for(int i=2;i<1000000;i++){
            if(prime[i] && newnum%i==0){
                sum+=i;
            }
        }
        std::cout<<sum;
        return 0;

    }
```

Comment: This question is almost completely unanswerable in its current form.  What is the problem you're trying to solve?  What do you think is wrong with your code?  (Also, *please* comment your code - I think part of the reason you're having trouble is that you have one giant long function)

Comment: the first(?) bug is that you are assuming that prime[] is originally full of zeroes.  edit: no, ones?!

Comment: The unchecked `while(1)` looks risky to me. Have you checked the result of your sieve code?

Comment: i am not event getting to std::cout<<"ll" statement

Comment: well it doesn't end in a newline so is probably buffered.  try "111\n" (@Tinctorius's soln below is better).

Comment: i have updated the question with the problem i am trying to solve

Comment: prime[newnum] will be called when newnum>1000000

Comment: Like @andrewcooke mentions, that's because it's still in the output buffer. Replace that line with `std::cout<<"lll"<<std::endl;`.

Comment: yes , the problem is in while loop

Comment: http://codepad.org/xZ5Es3Ow

Comment: @Jason is the fibonacii number just greater then 227000 is more then 1000000

Comment: Can you clarify the problem?  You appear to be searching for a prime number f, then computing its factors.  This seems strange as a prime number will always have factors of 1 and f and no others.

Comment: the problem is you have to find the first fibonacci number greater then 227000 which is also a prime  and return the sum of all its prime divisors+1

Comment: sorry i have updayed the question its finding sum of prime divisors of that prime number+1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One reason you may get a segmentation fault is that you are getting a stack overflow due to placing 1 million integers on the stack.

Another reason is that primes is not initialised so the while loop may go too far and access primes beyond the limits of the array.

To fix this you need to:

1. Allocate array on the heap (or simply change it to be global)
2. Initialise your primes array to contain 1's

It would be better if the while loop also guaranteed to terminate or you may access the prime array beyond bounds.

```
#include<iostream>
int prime[1000000];
int main(){
    int n = 227000;
    std::cout<<"lll";
    int i;
    for(i = 2; i<1000000;i++)
      prime[i]=1;
    for(i = 2; i<1000;i++){
        if(!prime[i]) continue;
        int j;
        for(j=i*i;j<1000000;j+=i){
            prime[j] = 0;
        }
    }

    int num = 1;
    int nextnum = 1;
    int newnum;
    while(1){
        newnum = num+nextnum;
        if(newnum>n && prime[newnum]) break;
        num = nextnum;
        nextnum = newnum;
    }
    int sum = 1;
    for(int i=2;i<1000000;i++){
        if(prime[i] && newnum%i==0){
            sum+=i;
        }
    }
    std::cout<<sum;
    return 0;

}
```

UPDATE

By the way, the second loop pointlessly tries to find factors of a prime number newnum.

I suspect the problem is actually to find something like the prime factors of the number (newnum+1) for which the code would change to

```
    int sum = 0;
    for(int i=2;i<1000000;i++){
        if(prime[i] && (newnum+1)%i==0){
            sum+=i;
        }
    }
```

Comment: allocating on the stack works just fine for me (but your code works too, if you include iostream).  is 32MB (64?) really too much for common stacks?

Comment: Thanks, for me (using g++ on cygwin) the stack overflow was significant (it segfaulted even with an immediate return) but other compilers may well vary.

Comment: huh, interesting.  for the record i am on linux amd64.

Comment: @PeterdeRivaz yes the segmentation fault is now gone , but the answer is incorrect , do you see any logical errors in code

Comment: Experiments suggest 510,000 ints are fine, but 515,000 behave badly.  My ints are 4 bytes, so this suggests only about 2megabytes of stack space.

Comment: oh i got bits and bytes confused earlier(!), sorry.  @Peter - algorithm issues might be worth a second q if noone answers.

Comment: @PeterdeRivaz you were right i have updated the question. But even with this i get the answer as 353 and the system is not accepting the answer. I think some minor bug is still there in code

Comment: I get 352 when I ran the program (note that I changed sum=1 to sum=0).

Comment: aah , sum=1 i was using when i i has written the code for finding primedivisors+1

Comment: check my answer. It's a little different.

Answer (score 2):

I would creating a loop to generate Fibonacci numbers until I found one larger than the input. Then I would check each to see if it's prime. It's much faster than generating a list of prime numbers.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<math.h>

bool isPrime(int number)
{
    for (int i=2;i<=sqrt(number);i++)
        if ((number%i)==0) return false;

    return true;
}


int main(){

    int n = 227000;

    int index=1;
    int nums[2];
    nums[0]=0;
    nums[1]=1;
    int currentFib = 0;

    while (currentFib <=n || !isPrime(currentFib))
    {
        //Calculate the next fib
        index = (index+1)%2;
        nums[index] = nums[0]+nums[1];
        currentFib = nums[index];
        cout<<"Fibb "<<currentFib<<endl;
    }

    return currentFib;
}
```

Code returned 514229, which is both prime and a Fibonacci number and greater than 227000.

Answer (score 0):

The prime fibonacci numbers are given at [A005478](http://oeis.org/A005478). The smallest prime fibonacci number greater than 227000 is 514229. You might enjoy [this entry](http://programmingpraxis.com/2010/10/29/fibonacci-primes/) at my blog.